# Make a change to a previous page version

Tags: publishing-page, versioning

If I want to immediatly change some fields on a page, but that page is currently checked out can I?

1. Save that checked out version without publishing it.
2. Get the last published version, change my fields on that version, publish that version again.
3. Then checkout the page again and slap on the values of that previously saved checked out version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is checked out, then you have to wait until the item is checked in. If you have full control over the library, you can force a check in of the file and discard that person's changes, then take ownership of the page.